# Webview CaptureAsync .net Maui Desktop

Tags: android, .net, maui-windows

```
    bool iscom=  webView.CaptureAsync().IsCompleted;
    var stream = await webView.CaptureAsync();
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream("image.png", FileMode.Create))
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream, ScreenshotFormat.Png, 100);
    }
```

This code is working fine on Android Phone but on Win Desktop it is returning Blank image and bool iscom return true in case of Android and on Win Desktop it always return false.

Any workaround for this

Comment: For Maui Desktop, it is actually winui3. Are you using WebView2?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT No

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you provided, and it return false as you said that.

For Maui Desktop, it actually uses [WebView2](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Core/src/Platform/Windows/MauiWebView.cs). But there is no method for CaptureAsync. I think that's what's causing the false to be returned.

You can [report it on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).